# How to use odd symbols in HTML5 pattern?

Tags: java, html, scala

How can I use symbols like:
[]\
in the HTML5 pattern, such that the symbols actually a are part of the pattern? I'm using Scala / Java to wrap HTML5.

For example, some code I use for it looks like:

```
regexp = '((?=.*[!\\d~@#$^*()_+=\\[\\]{}|\\,.?: -])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,})'
```

and is used like this:

```
'pattern -> Html(regexp),
```

in a form on an inputText. 'pattern is pattern attribute in html and Html(regexp) translates regexp to a html text. In HTML it would be represented like this: `pattern="((?=.*[!\d~@#$^*()_+=[]{}|\,.?: -])(?=.*[a-zæøå])(?=.*[A-ZÆØÅ]).{8,})"` .

The regexp works as intended on my backend, but on the frontend, in HTML5, it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: What *actually gets output to the HTML*? E.g., what does your browser see?

Comment: What do you need to show and render?

Comment: It appears to output _((?=.*[!\d~@#$^*()_+=\[\]{}|\,.?: -])(?=.*[a-zæøå])(?=.*[A-ZÆØÅ]).{8,})_. It's a pattern used for a form. The user types in something and presses submit. The HTML5 pattern should then validate whether the input is valid or invalid.

Comment: Using this regexp: _((?=.*[!\\d~@#$^*()_+={}|,.?: -])(?=.*[a-zæøå])(?=.*[A-ZÆØÅ]).{8,})_ works, but then I cannot use these symbols: []\.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Forgot to refer to you :-)

Comment: @acostela and same with you.